# Smarter navigation plugin and custom taxonomies

Tags: plugins, custom-taxonomy, terms

I am trying to make work [Smarter Navigation](http://wordpress.org/plugins/smarter-navigation/installation/)'s `get_referrer_category()` with a custom taxonomy that I have created. The custom taxonomy I've included into functions.php is the following:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_colors_nonhierarchical_taxonomy', 0 );

function create_colors_nonhierarchical_taxonomy() {

  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x( 'Colors', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'Color', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Colors' ),
    'popular_items' => __( 'Popular Colors' ),
    'all_items' => __( 'All Colors' ),
    'parent_item' => null,
    'parent_item_colon' => null,
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Color' ), 
    'update_item' => __( 'Update Color' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Color' ),
    'new_item_name' => __( 'New Color Name' ),
    'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate colors with commas' ),
    'add_or_remove_items' => __( 'Add or remove colors' ),
    'choose_from_most_used' => __( 'Choose from the most used colors' ),
    'menu_name' => __( 'Colors' ),
  ); 

  register_taxonomy('colors','post',array(
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'color' ),
  ));
}
```

Now, as I need to highlight not only the category, but also the tag and the custom taxonomy that the user came from, I've changed the following block of code inside [this plugin file](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/smarter-navigation/trunk/template-tags.php):

```
// Retrieve the category, based on the referrer URL. Useful if you have posts with multiple categories
function get_referrer_category() {
    global $posts;

    if ( ! $referrer_url = get_referrer_url( false ) )
        return false;

    foreach ( get_the_category( $posts[0]->ID ) as $cat ) {
        $cat_link = get_category_link( $cat->term_id );

        if ( false !== strpos( $referrer_url, $cat_link ) )
            return $cat;
    }

    foreach ( get_the_tags( $posts[0]->ID ) as $tag ) {
        $tag_link = get_tag_link( $tag->term_id );

        if ( false !== strpos( $referrer_url, $tag_link ) )
            return $tag;
    }

    foreach ( get_the_terms( $posts[0]->ID, 'color' ) as $term ) {
        $term_link = get_term_link( $term->term_id );

        if ( false !== strpos( $referrer_url, $term_link ) )
            return $term;
    }

    return false;
}
```

and I've added these lines to content-single.php:

```
<?php
  if ( $cat = get_referrer_category() )
    echo '<span>Exploring // <a href="' . get_category_link( $cat->term_id ) . '">' . $cat->slug . '</a>';
?>
```

Category and tags work fine, but I still can't display custom taxonomies. I am not good at all with PHP and I am quite sure I am missing something. Help is greatly appreciated ;)

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out the issue. Here is the working code:

```
foreach ( get_the_terms( $posts[0]->ID, 'colors' ) as $term ) {
    $term_link = get_term_link( $term, 'colors' );

    if ( false !== strpos( $referrer_url, $term_link ) )
        return $term;
}
```